# What does it mean to champion a faction in Pandaria content?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In the reputation pane you can select one of the Pandaria factions to champion and it states: "You will earn bonus reputation for the selected faction for various activities."

At first I assumed this meant dungeon rep, á la previous expansions, but when I selected the Tillers and did a heroic dungeon I didn't get any Tillers rep.

What does championing a reputation do and does it have the same effect for every faction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding should be correct, but there are some limitations, namely that:

1. It has to be your first heroic dungeon of the day;
2. You have to random queue for it;
3. It has to be a level-appropriate dungeon (i.e. WoD dungeon at lvl
   100)

From the [patch notes](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/8896363/#raids_dungeons):

> You can now earn bonus reputation for your first dungeon and scenario
>   of the day. You can select which reputation you choose to champion by
>   selecting it from the reputation panel on the character screen. When
>   you queue for a dungeon or scenario, the UI will remind you which
>   reputation you are championing and allow you to change the reputation
>   from there. (You cannot change that reputation once you are in the
>   dungeon or scenario.)

Also see [this thread](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/18194574572) for more information, including the indication that the process still worked post-MoP, and is my source for the third requirement above.

I cannot find any indication that this feature was removed (for level 91+) or altered in the last six months, so I have no answers if you're meeting those three requirements and still not gaining reputation.

Comment: It hasn't been removed, (as of a week ago) but it is still only valid for MoP content, and doesn't translate to Draenor in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Championing a faction causes you to gain reputation with said faction by running dungeons.  This can be done for Mists factions through the faction window, and for Wrath and Cata factions by wearing specific tabards.

Comment: This is a good start, but I think you should mention the differences between how championing works across the expansions.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on a 100 and a 90.  It only works for a level 90 who can que for Pandaria heroic dungeons and scenarios.  Once you hit 91 poof.  No longer eligible.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. This seems more like a comment to the top answer, rathern than a self sustained answer. I recommend taking our [tour] to see how our site works and either gathering enough reputation to either post this as a comment or editing it to the point it's a self sustained answer to the posted question.